# Confusion about Numerical Stability

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, stability-theory

Numerical Analysis is giving me some trouble. In specific, I'm highly confused by our definition of numerical stability. I'm hoping some of you can help me clear my confusion.

**Definition.** An algorithm $\hat{f}$ for a problem $f$ is called *stable* if$$ \| \hat{f}(x) - f(\tilde{x}) \|_{\text{rel}} = \mathcal{O}(\varepsilon_{\text{mach}})$$ for some suitably chosen $\tilde{x}$ with $\|x-\tilde{x} \|_{\text{rel}} = \mathcal{O}(\varepsilon_{\text{mach}})$.

So what do I do in practice to prove stability/instability? It may be my unfamiliarity with Landau notation in numerical purposes. Let me try to have a guess.

**Proving Stability:** Show that there exists a constant $c > 0$ such that: There exists a constant $C > 0$ such that there exists a $\tilde{x}$ with $\|x-\tilde{x} \|_{\text{rel}} < c \varepsilon_{\text{mach}}$ for each sufficiently small $\varepsilon_{\text{mach}} > 0$ such that$$\| \hat{f}(x) - f(\tilde{x}) \|_{\text{rel}} < C \varepsilon_{\text{mach}}$$
Do I read the Landau symbols correctly?

**Proving Instability:** Show that such $c > 0$ does not exist.

Is that how you would prove stability in practice? For instance, would you start by defining such constants to prove that $x \mapsto \log(1 \oplus \operatorname{fl}(x))$ is instable?

**EDIT:** Perhaps this seems more convenient: Take $\tilde{x} = (1+c \varepsilon_{\text{mach}})x$ and show that the difference of functions also scales in $\varepsilon_{\text{mach}}$. As for instability, anytime we do that, the result will not decrease as quickly.
I guess that's how one should go about that?

Comment: I'd say you're right. If it helps, my "laymen" definition of stability is: small perturbations in the data imply small perturbations in the result. 
But (surely it's abundantly obvious) keep in mind that if $x$ is a vector, you need a norm of the difference $\| x - \bar{x} \|$ to be small so the formula for $\bar{x}$ at the bottom works only in the scalar case.

Comment: Oh right, true, thanks. Yeah, I do know the intuition for stability, though I‘m having trouble working with it.